# How to increase cookies storage limit(4096) in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cookies, storage

I have implemented cookies using jquery and its working fine if  center name's array length is less than 4096 byte.

but i have to store large amount of  center name's array in cookies (more than 4096 byte).
so when i store center name more than 4096 byte then it can not store in cookies due to length of cookies.

So my question is below

**Is there any way to increase storage length of cookies if center name's array is more than 4096 byte in chrome**

Cookies length set near to max length after this length no new center name array is stored

[image]

Note:
(1) center name is an jquery array eg.(["1","2",etc])
(2) this question is only for chrome browser its working fine in IE 10

hope someone will help..

Thanks

Comment: In a modern browser like Chrome you have better client-side storage alternatives. It's not a good idea to add an overhead of more than 4KB to every HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [HTML5 localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) that allows you to store larger amounts of data instead of passing them back and forth using cookies.

> **Storage size**
>
> Web storage provides far greater storage capacity (5 MB per origin in
>   Google Chrome,[6] Mozilla Firefox,[7] and Opera; 10 MB per storage
>   area in Internet Explorer;[8] 25MB per origin on BlackBerry 10
>   devices) compared to 4 kB (around 1000 times less space) available to
>   cookies.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage